# Export solution in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 fails

Tags: export, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Exporting a solution in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 used to work fine. However, since this week there is something odd happening with exporting a solution. Where I used to get a pop-up window that showed Dynamics was busy creating a ZIP-file for my solution, this window now does not pop-up anymore and no ZIP-file is generated. When I look in the server log, the following error is logged:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 8/28/2014 12:05:02 PM 
Event time (UTC): 8/28/2014 10:05:02 AM 
Event ID: 32272fa9722b4d90acbb41ebb3f6e235 
Event sequence: 125 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-130536937393405660 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\ 
    Machine name: <censored>

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2768 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: <censored> 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x800704CD.
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6.FlushCore(Byte[] status, Byte[] header, Int32 keepConnected, Int32 totalBodySize, Int32 numBodyFragments, IntPtr[] bodyFragments, Int32[] bodyFragmentLengths, Int32 doneWithSession, Int32 finalStatus, Boolean& async)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.FlushCachedResponse(Boolean isFinal)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Dialogs.ExportSolutionPage.ExportSolution(String ismanaged, String optionXml)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Dialogs.ExportSolutionPage.ConfigureForm()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppUIPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: <censored>/_grid/cmds/dlg_exportsolution.aspx?appSolutionId={CC88C481-F719-E311-A1B1-005056A81986}&command=exportsolution&ismanaged=0&optionxml=falsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse 
    Request path: /CRMTST/_grid/cmds/dlg_exportsolution.aspx 
    User host address: <censored>
    User: <censored> 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: <censored>

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 7 
    Thread account name: <censored>
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6.FlushCore(Byte[] status, Byte[] header, Int32 keepConnected, Int32 totalBodySize, Int32 numBodyFragments, IntPtr[] bodyFragments, Int32[] bodyFragmentLengths, Int32 doneWithSession, Int32 finalStatus, Boolean& async)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.FlushCachedResponse(Boolean isFinal)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Dialogs.ExportSolutionPage.ExportSolution(String ismanaged, String optionXml)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Dialogs.ExportSolutionPage.ConfigureForm()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppUIPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

Googling for the error code of the `HttpException` (`0x800704CD`), states that this error code indicates that the request was canceled. That would explain why the pop-up never appears, it is immediately canceled.

The strange thing is that this behavior is new, which leads me to think that either the browsers have been updated or this has been caused by a Windows update. The Dynamics CRM software itself has not been updated.

The export functionality itself works fine, which I verified by directly pasting the export request URL in the browser. This will return the ZIP file without the error being logged in the event log.

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi @Erik have you tried running in compatibility mode? Or IIS Reset?

Comment: @Scorpion I have done an IIS reset. Have not yet tried to run in compatibility mode, but I wonder if Dynamics would work in compatibility mode.

Comment: Depends on the version of your IE and CRM rollup. I had similar issues in past with IE 10 and IE Compatibility mode solved it.

Comment: @Scorpion I added the website to my trusted sites, enabled compatibility mode but it still does not show the pop-up. This might be due to my browser being IE11.

Comment: Can you confirm your rollup number?

Comment: The rollup number is 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the version of your IE and CRM rollup. But sometimes Compatibility mode solves the problem. I had similar issues in past with IE 10 and IE Compatibility mode solved it.

If you are on rollup 10 and your IE version is also 10, you need to switch to compatibility mode. Ref: [Support with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Internet Explorer 10](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2743941)

Please check this link: [Configuring Settings for IE 10 and CRM 2011](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/03/25/configuring-ie-10-and-crm-2011/)

Comment: This works, a bit. I now do get the ZIP-file, even though the pop-up is never shown. My rollup number is 13 by the way.